# iOS - Read HealthKit SOS Contacts

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

Apple describes how the iPhone user may enter in emergency contacts here:

[Use Emergency SOS on your iPhone](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT208076#soscontacts)

---

There seems to be no information available as to if that data is accessible using the current HealthKit APIs provided by Apple.

Is it possible to read this data provided the user grants permission?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have access to Emergency Contacts, it's a requested feature that HIPPA laws are preventing, you can go here to see what you do have access to.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkhealthstore